# Android Sqlite Constraint failed

Tags: android, sqlite, constraints

Below is the values that I am inserting using ContentValues in android. While inserting values I am getting constraint failed

```
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String time = hour_ + ":" + minute_;
    String date = day_ + "/" + month_ + "/" + year_;
    EditText task = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taskDetail);
    values.put(ToDoDatabase.TASK, task.getText().toString());
    values.put(ToDoDatabase.TASK_TIME, time);
    values.put(ToDoDatabase.TASK_DATE, date);
    values.put(ToDoDatabase.TASK_NAME_FORMAT_DATE,
            timeFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(date)));
    toDoDatabase.insert(ToDoDatabase.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Below given is code from my sub class of SqliteOpenHelper.

```
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ToDo";
static final int DATABSE_VERSION = 1;
static final String ROW_ID = "_id";
static final String TASK = "task";
static final String TASK_TIME = "task_time";
static final String TASK_DATE = "task_date";
static final String TASK_STATUS = "task_status";
static final String TASK_NAME_FORMAT_DATE = "task_name_format_date";
static final String TABLE_NAME = "ToDoTable";

static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( "
        + ROW_ID + " INTEGER AUTOTINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , " + TASK
        + " VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL , " + TASK_TIME
        + " VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , " + TASK_DATE + " DATE NOT NULL , "
        + TASK_STATUS + " BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'FALSE' , "
        + TASK_NAME_FORMAT_DATE + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );";

public ToDoDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABSE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        Log.d("Result", "Success");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("Result", "Fail");
    }
}
```

The problem is that i am not able to figure out the reason for constraint fail. 
The logCat output is

```
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380): Error inserting task_date=0/0/0 task_name_format_date=30,Sunday, November , '02 task=ask task_time=0:0
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:117)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1724)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1597)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at com.softmya.softlist.TaskAdding.saveData(TaskAdding.java:129)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at com.softmya.softlist.TaskAdding.onOptionsItemSelected(TaskAdding.java:108)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:366)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:159)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:130)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:295)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:955)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
     10-13 1121:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:490)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:108)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
    10-13 11:21:34.475: E/SQLiteDatabase(2380):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: May be you are inserting a `null` value in a non-null column ? Also in your table definition I saw `AUTOTINCREMENT`, a typo ?

Comment: yes, AUTOTINCREMENT is the problem.you have to write AUTOINCREMENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `AUTOTINCREMENT`. If I were you I'd use an OR mapper like ORMLite or Greendao, saves all the hassle of building queries.